# Assigning jobs to in-game entities to carry out tasks (move object, build item etc.)

Tags: architecture

I'm not really sure what to call this so I'm struggling to Google for solutions.

Basically my game will have resources (wood, stone, etc) that are "delivered" to a point on the map. I want worker entities to collect resources and deliver them to where they need to be (a building site or put them in storage).

My problem is that I don't know how to structure this kind of "job queue".

My first idea was that when a resource is delivered it creates a "job" object in a queue. Then in the game cycle I'll find all workers that are idle, pop the next job off the stack and assign it to him.

Am I heading down the right path? Is there a better way of doing this? Can someone tell me what I should be Googling to find examples of what I'm trying to achieve?

Comment: Your idea sounds reasonable. What is the actual question?

Comment: I'd agree, this sounds like a solution that meets your goals of serving up jobs to workers. Are you encountering problems with it, or trying to add another feature it doesn't support out of the box (like prioritizing close jobs to minimize unnecessary travel)? If you want us to judge the suitability of this solution to your game, you're probably in a better position to do that than we are, since you know far more about your game and how it should play than we can glean from a few paragraphs. ;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A queue is a reasonable approach: when a resource is spawned in the world, put a job in the queue for somebody to go pick it up. When a worker is idle, dequeue a job and process it. If no jobs are in the queue, sit around and have a drink.

You may want to add additional layers of abstraction for realism, depending on your game mechanics. For example, by queuing up the jobs immediately when a resource spawns, your workers are basically all-seeing. They will always "know" that resources are available and where they are. If that's a problem you can introduce a layer of abstraction where nothing happens when a resource is spawn (except it is marked as "undiscovered") and any unit that gets within *X* distance or otherwise has an undiscovered resource end up in its line-of-sight causes the resource to be marked as "discovered" and *then* queues up the work order.